# UnifiedNativeAdView, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: java, admob, native-ads, unifiednativeadview

I added the required dependency. But the Android Studio is showing the below line. Adview is showing and no other issue. I checked everything carefully, But I see the below time every time.

> com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView, was not found in the project or the libraries

Answer (score 9):

That was deprecated and got replaced with this tag NativeAdView

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you were using SDK v20

for ex:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0' // end more
```

you have to notice this changes.

[image: list changes]
There a lot of class has been renamed and removed. For detail [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration)

Comment: this is very helpful to change old packages with new one. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of google ads you're using. It could be the dependency you have is an older version. Is it >= 17.0.0? Check the release notes https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes?hl=es

Comment: I am using the latest version. Here is the dependency.
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently upgraded to admob 20.1.0?

Comment: I am using the latest version. Here is the dependency. 
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'.

Comment: This class has been replaced by NativeAdView.
You can downgrade to 19.7.0 or migrate your code 
here is the migration link
 https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration